# How to show images from json file using JQuery on an HTML Page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I'm trying to create a gallery where the image that I select in the thumbnail zone, shows on the "main area" and could have the option through the arrows go to the back or next image.

I have the **gallery_json.js**

```
{
      "album": {
        "name": "Project's name"
      },
      "photos": [
        {
          "id":"1",
          "image":"img/image_1.jpg",
          "thumb_url":"test_images/thumb_1.jpg",
          "title":"This is a image",
          "date":"May, 2010",
          "location":"Barcelona"
        },{
          "id":"2",
          "image":"img/image_2.jpg",
          "thumb_url":"test_images/thumb_2.jpg",
          "title":"This is image 2",
          "date":"December, 2014",
          "location":"Chile"},
        {...}]}
```

and the **Scripts.js**

```
$(document).ready( function(){

$.getJSON('js/gallery.json', function (data) {
    $.each(data.photos, function (i, f) {
        var img = "<li><img id='" + f.id + "' src='" + f.thumb_url + "' alt='" + f.title + "' /></li>";
        $("ul").append(img);
        $("#Thumbnail").click( function(){
            var fullImg = "<li data-full-url='" + f.image +"'></li><li caption='" + f.title + "'></li>";
            $(".mainImage").select(fullImg);
        });
    });
});

$('#prevImg').click( function(){

});
```

});

I can't find the way to show the images in the index.html

```
</!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Gallery Challenge</title>
        <link href="assets/css/gallery_json.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="assets/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <h1>Dinamic gallery</h1>
        </header>

        <section id="Main">     
        <div  class="mainImage">

        </div>
        <div class="prevButton">
            <button id="prevImg" class="btnPrev"></button>      
        </div>
        <div class="nextButton">
            <button id="NextImg" class="btnNext"></button>
        </div>          
    </section>
    <section id="Thumbnail" >
        <div id="json-gallery">
            <ul></ul>
        </div>
    </section>


    <!-- JavaScript -->
    <script src="assets/js/gallery_json.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/scripts.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I would appreciate your support. Thank you so much!

Comment: So far you've got code that displays the thumbs, and that's all, correct? You'll probably want to add click event listeners to the thumbnails, then code to display the image in the page - the image display element should have areas you can click to navigate next/prev

Comment: `UL` accepts only `LI`, not `<br />` - be careful what you desire. Also, yeah, where's your `<img src="" alt="">` ??

Comment: Are you still working in javascript and jquery?????

Comment: What is the result of your code? please provide a screenshot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Unless this is some legacy system consider using an alternative to jQuery like Angular 2, React, Vue or anything that have data binding concept implemented. As you are not working on e.g. server side generated HTML it would be a good use case for such frameworks / libraries over jQuery.
2. Do not use `<br />` tag nested in `<ul>` and `</ul>` tags. Use only `<li>` and `</li>` pairs in this context. You are using multiple `<li>` tags for a single list element. Better use a single one with multiple `<div>` tags inside for wrapping URL, caption, date, etc. For spacing purposes use CSS class or refer to `<li>` element directly. Classes are more safe as referring to styling scope.
3. If you stick with jQuery you can use "on" event to handle thumbnail clicks, like that: `$('ul').on('click', 'li', function() { // handle showing big image here });` - please check docs for details.
4. To get a full image URL in click event handling code you can write it first for later use in a `<li>` tag like `"<li data-full-url='" + f.image +"'>"`. It is still not so elegant solution. Data binding mentioned in point 1) would be more clean and would provide better layers separation.
5. Handling arrows is yet another event and iteration over objects array defined in JSON. You have all data required. The "id" property could be written as Integer or casted to it from String, then incremented / decremented as needed. Edge cases are when you show first or last elements. You can either disable "previous" / "next" feature in such case or cycle to first / last element. UX choice.

Comment: Thank u @HybridLizard for your Advice. If u see, I changed the scripts.js even I didn't apply the click event still. I'm getting stuck in this :/

Comment: Please read jQuery docs for getting the difference between `click` and `on` events. 

I suggest you read more docs, e.g. [link](https://developer.mozilla.org) can be a good start. Also study jQuery docs as you choose that library. Be sure to know some native HTML, CSS, JS first.

Get grasp of basic stuff first. Do some tutorials. Then you can come back to this. If you will still having troubles, please ask more specific questions.

There is no point to rewrite almost entire "widget" here. There are tutorials for that or ready-to-use plugins depending on needs and preferences. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can use 3rd party libraries to achieve that.

http://photoswipe.com/documentation/getting-started.html